# FileMaker SQL Borders

Tags: html, sql, filemaker

I'm trying to use SQL HTML with FileMaker Pro 13. I was able Code a Web Viewer layout to show the Columns of my Data, however the borders are not showing up and I'm not sure why. Please let me know if someone know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
"data:text/html,"  & 

Let (
[
$tableRows = ExecuteSQL(
"SELECT '<tr>
<td>' || ID_BAR_Parent, BAR_Name, Project_Name || '</td>
</tr>'
FROM BAR_Parent
WHERE ID_BAR_Parent    > 1
ORDER BY BAR_Name, Project_Name";

"</td>¶  <td>"; ¶)
];
"<html>
<head>
<style type = \"text/css\">
#Bar_Parent
{
font-family:\"Trebuchet MS\”, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#Bar_Parent td, #Bar_Parent th
{
font-size:1em;
border:3px solid #2020AA;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#Bar_Parent th
{
font-size:1.1em;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#2120AA;
color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style=\"border:0; margin: 0;\">
<table id = \"BAR_Parent\">
<tr align = \"left\"><th>ID</th><th>BAR Name</th><th>Project Name</th></tr>" & 
$tableRows & "
</table>
</body>
</html>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of the CSS question rather than FileMaker

If you look at this line:

> font-family:\"Trebuchet MS\”, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

the second quotation mark after Trebuchet MS is incorrect - it is U+201D : (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) instead of simple U+0022, QUOTATION MARK.

Change to

```
font-family:\"Trebuchet MS\", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

or to

```
font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

and it should work.

The simplest way to check this is to test your code in a web browser before you code for the FileMaker webviewer